# Showing a function is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am trying to show that $$h\colon X \to X \times Y, x \mapsto x \times y_0$$ where $y_0$ is fixed is continuous. I have taken $U \times V \subset X \times Y$ and said that

$$h^{-1}(U \times V) = \{x \mid (x, y_0) \in U \times V\}.$$

I must show that this is an open subset of $X$, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Consider two cases: $y_0\in V$, and $y_0\notin V$. Also, I think you meant to write $U\times V$ instead of $h_1^{-1}(U\times V)$ in the set specification.

Comment: Two cases: (i) $y_0\notin V$, (ii) $y_0\in V$. If (i), then $h^{-1}(U\times V) = \emptyset$ is open, so suppose (ii). Then $h^{-1}(U\times V) = U$ (why?)

Comment: @StefanHamcke I corrected that. And got rid of the pointless subscript on $h^{-1}$.

Comment: @BrianO (ii) is what confused me. Is it due to $(x, y_0) \in U \times U$? Why does this give us the result?

Comment: $\in U\times V$ you mean. You need to show that the inverse image under $h$ of any open set in $X\times Y$ is open in $X$. The basic open sets in $X\times Y$ are sets $U\times V$ where $U, V$ are open (in $X,Y$ respectively). So....

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to why $h^{-1}(U\times V) = U$ @BrianO ?

Comment: $\{x \mid (x, y_0) \in U \times V\}$ = $\{x \mid x \in U \text{ and } y_0\in V\}$. So if $y_0\in V$, it's the same set as $\{x \mid x \in U\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h^{-1}[U \times V] = \{x \in X: (x,y_0) \in U \times V \} = \{x \in X: x \in U, y_0 \in V\}$. This set is empty if $y_0 \notin V$. Otherwise it equals $\{x: x \in U \} = U$. So $h^{-1}[U \times V] = \emptyset$ or $h^{-1}[U \times V] = U$, both of which are open.

Also note that $h[U] = U \times \{y_0\} = (U \times Y) \cap (X \times \{y_0\})$, so that $h$ is also open as a function between $X$ and the subspace $X \times \{y_0\}$ (of course the latter in its subspace topology w.r.t. $X \times Y$). I.e. $h$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $h[X] = X \times \{y_0\}$.